# error en mounted() VueJs, Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this is undefined al guardar dato en variable

Tags: firebase, vue.js

Buen dia,

Tengo el siguiente código que me guarda el email del usuario logueado, estoy usando Firebase, se autentica bien sin lio en otra funcion que no pongo aca, el problema es que necesito guardar en la variable emailUsuarioLogueado el email del usuario logueado para usarlo luego, esto dado el caso que se refresque la pagina, leí que eso se hace en mounted();

```
new Vue({
 el:'#app',
 data:{
  usuario:"",
  emailUsuarioLogueado:"",
  contrasena:""
 },
 mounted(){
     function detectarUsuarioLogueado(){
       onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
       if(user != null)
       {
         //aqui me funciona bien, me muestra el correo del usuario logueado
         console.log("usuario logueado:" + user.email);
         //aqui es donde me da el error                              
         this.emailUsuarioLogueado = user.email; 
       }else{
         //aqui tambien me funciona
         console.log("la sesion esta sesion cerrada");                                                                
       }      
    })                     
  }

 //llamo la funcion 
 detectarUsuarioLogueado();
 //aqui entonces tambien me da error ya que arriba también está mal
 //console.log(this.emailUsuarioLogueado);
});
```

muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Tíícamente, la llamada `detectarUsuarioLogueado()` es lo que iría en `mounted()`, y la declaración de la función `detectarUsuarioLogueado() {...}` iría en la propiedad `methods`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ creo que estás en lo correcto, una duda que me surge es que hace una ``function declaration`` (detectarUsuarioLogueado) y luego, en su interior, una ``arrow function`` (onAuthStateChanged). En esta segunda funcion, cuando llama a ``this``, no está haciendo referencia al contexto de la funcion ``detectarUsuarioLogueado`` (cuando deberia hacer referencia al contexto del componente)? Yo pa ahorrarme esos inconvenientes haria todo con arrows function (dentro de los métodos, como decis) para que this siempre esté en el mismo contexto.